# Disassemble ELF binary without section headers (program headers only) using objdump

Tags: elf, binutils

I've got an ELF binary that contains nothing but two LOAD segments in the program header table, one for code and one for data. `readelf -a` tells me there's no section headers.

If I attempt do disassemble the ARM binary on my amd64 machine with ARM cross binutils, it doesn't give me proper output. However, as far as I understand, the binary's architecture shouldn't be relevant for this question, since the issue is ELF-related.

```
$ file ./binary
./binary: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, stripped

$ arm-linux-gnueabi-objdump -d ./binary 

./binary:     file format elf32-littlearm

$ arm-linux-gnueabi-objdump -x ./binary 

./binary:     file format elf32-littlearm
./binary
architecture: arm, flags 0x00000102:
EXEC_P, D_PAGED
start address 0x0004c8d8

Program Header:
    LOAD off    0x00000000 vaddr 0x00010000 paddr 0x00010000 align 2**16
         filesz 0x0003d27e memsz 0x0003d27e flags r-x
    LOAD off    0x00005c78 vaddr 0x00085c78 paddr 0x00085c78 align 2**16
         filesz 0x00000000 memsz 0x00000000 flags rw-
   STACK off    0x00000000 vaddr 0x00000000 paddr 0x00000000 align 2**4
         filesz 0x00000000 memsz 0x00000000 flags rw-
private flags = 5000400: [Version5 EABI] [hard-float ABI]

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA       LMA       File off  Algn
SYMBOL TABLE:
no symbols
```

**Is there a way to make objdump disassemble ELF segments?**

Comment: Can you edit the question to show the output of `arm-linux-gnueabi-objdump -x ./binary`?

Comment: @icarus: Did it. As you can see, there's only the two LOAD segments, but no sections.

Comment: I came across this when I packed an executable with upx. If this is the case here then the disassembly is going to be of limited value. Making a copy of the binary and running `upx -d copy_of_binary` will  help. Otherwise I can can suggest a partial solution using gdb.

Comment: @icarus: Will try it tomorrow. But I don't think it's compressed because disassembling it with tools like radare works fine. Not totally sure though, but I'll check whether the assembly actually makes sense.